# Android Chronometer resume function

Tags: android, chronometer

I mm trying to create a resume button in my Android app using Chronometer. So far I have this code snippet for the resume method:

```
private long pauseResume() {

    long timeWhenStopped = chronometer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    return timeWhenStopped;

}
```

And here's the code for the resume button:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(v.getId()) {

          ...

          case R.id.resume_button:                
              chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + pauseResume());
              chronometer.start();    
              break;

      }
}
```

THE PROBLEM: Example, when I pause the timer at 00:05 and then I press the resume button 10 seconds later, the timer will resume counting at 00:15.

I want it to start at 00:05 again, not 00:15, because as it is a "resume" function.

I am very glad you could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

A little bit too late but it might help others. I think this is the solution to your problem.

Start / Resume chronometer:

```
private void chronoStart()
{
    // on first start
    if ( mLastStopTime == 0 )
        mChronometer.setBase( SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() );
    // on resume after pause
    else
    {
        long intervalOnPause = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastStopTime);
        mChronometer.setBase( mChronometer.getBase() + intervalOnPause );
    }

    mChronometer.start();
}
```

Pause chronometer:

```
private void chronoPause()
{
    mChronometer.stop();

    mLastStopTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
}
```

You need to **remember last chronometer stop time**.

On resume, you calculate how long it took between the last stop time and the new start time. When you have this interval you just **add the interval to your chronometer base time** (you "move" original start time).

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 2):

Chronometer has used for implements a simple timer.You can give it a start time in the `elapsedRealtime()` timebase, and it counts up from that, or if you don't give it a base time, it will use the time at which you call `start()`.

```
long timeWhenStopped = 0;
```

Update the value of the variable when you stop the chronometer like this:

```
timeWhenStopped = mChronometer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
mChronometer.stop();
```

We will also use this variable to adjust the chronometer before starting it:

```
mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
mChronometer.start();
```

And finally if you have a way to reset your chronometer then you should remember to also reset the timeWhenStopped variable. Something like this:

```
mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
timeWhenStopped = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

here's a kotlin version:

```
private var chronometerPausedTime: Long = 0

// to start the chronometer with 00:00
private fun Chronometer.startFromZero() {
    base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    start()
}

private fun Chronometer.pause() {
    chronometerPausedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - this.base
    stop()
}

private fun Chronometer.resume() {
    base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometerPausedTime
    chronometerPausedTime = 0
    start()
}
```

to use:

```
binding.chronometer.startFromZero()

//pause
binding.chronometer.pause()

//resume
binding.chronometer.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps...

We need a member variable to hold the time when the chronometer is paused. let's say that is "timeWhenChronometerIsPaused"

```
var timeWhenChronometerIsPaused:Long = 0
```

to start the chronometer set the base as elaspedRealTime

```
fun startChronometer(){
    chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    chronometer.start()
}
```

when the chronometer is paused save the time in timeWhenChronometerIsPaused variable

```
fun pauseChronometer(){
    timeWhenChronometerIsPaused = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase()
    chronometer.stop()
}
```

To resume the chronometer set the base as difference of current time and timeWhenChronometerIsPaused, and reset timeWhenChronometerIsPaused to 0

```
fun resumeChronometer(){
    chronometer.base = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timeWhenChronometerIsPaused
    timeWhenChronometerIsPaused = 0
}
```

Finally when the elapsed time is needed to calculate use "timeWhenChronometerIsPaused" if its value is not zero otherwise use (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.base)

```
fun getElapsedTime(): String {

    val elapsedMillis: Long = if (timeWhenChronometerIsPaused > 0)
        timeWhenChronometerIsPaused
    else
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.base

    val hours = (elapsedMillis / 3600000).toInt()
    val minutes = (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000).toInt() / 60000
    val seconds = (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000).toInt() / 1000
    val millis = (elapsedMillis - hours * 3600000 - minutes * 60000 - seconds * 1000).toInt()

    return "$hours:$minutes:$seconds:$millis"
}
```